# HTML5 iframe element not showing source url

Tags: html, iframe

I have used the following code but it does not show the content from source.I also tried using `"//www.w3schools.com"` instead of `"https://www.w3schools.com"` but it's not working.

My Code is as follow

```
<iframe src='https://www.w3schools.com' height="400" width="600" ></iframe>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Afd a border to the frame to see if the dimensions of the frame are ok. Not zero height.